# Is there a reverse-syntax version of "include?" in core/std-lib?

Tags: ruby

I commonly use the `[1, 2, 3].include? foo` idiom. There is nothing inherently wrong with this, but for readability's sake, it would be nice to be able to write `foo.is_in? [1, 2, 3]`. Does the core or standard library have a method that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such method in the standard. Implement it on your own:

```
class Object
  def is_in? a
    return a.include?(self)
  end
end
```

Note in the above code I never check the type of a so you will get an error if `include?` is not defined for a.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly in the same way as you want, but you can rewrite this

```
if [1, 2, 3].include? foo
  do_this
else
  do_that
end
```

to this:

```
case foo; when 1, 2, 3
  do_this
else
  do_that
end
```